# What's $\frac{\partial}{\partial A}A?$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

What's $\frac{\partial}{\partial A}A?$

In this [Python App](http://www.matrixcalculus.org/) it says that it's $I\otimes I$, but how can it be?

$\frac{\partial}{\partial A}A=\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}}A\right]=[\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}}A_{lk}]$

that equals to 1 only when $l=i$ and $k=j$,i.e.

$\frac{\partial}{\partial A_{ij}}A$ is a matrix of $A$'s dimensions, but only one entry is 1. All the others are zero...

Comment: You have basically done it. But your last phrase is wrong: it is not a matrix of $A$'s dimensions, but a four-rank tensor i.e. a beast with four suffices $B_{ijkl}$ if you like. This is another way of writing the tensor product $I\otimes I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python app cannot handle higher-order tensors, so it uses vectorization to flatten everything into vectors and proceeds as follows.
$$\eqalign{
 A &= IAI \cr
{\rm vec}(A) &= (I\otimes I)\,{\rm vec}(A) \cr
a &= (I\otimes I)\,a \cr
da &= (I\otimes I)\,da \cr
\frac{\partial a}{\partial a} &= I\otimes I \cr
}$$
The tensor gradient is actually very easy to calculate with index notation. 
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial A_{kl}} &= \delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}
}$$
which simply says that if the index pair $(i,j)$ is equal to the pair $(k,l)$ then the derivative is one, otherwise it's zero.

Comment: Thanks Greg! ;) P.S.: +1

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the underlying mapping is$f(A)=A$ hence the identity mapping on the vector space $V$ of all matrices. It is clearly linear, hence its derivative at $A$ in direction $\delta A$ is $
f'(A)\delta A=\delta A, $
which is given by
$$
f'(X) = I.
$$
Note, that both $f$ and $f'(A)$ are linear mappings from $V$ to $V$. 
The mapping $f'$ is a mapping from $V$ to $L(V,V)$.

The kronecker product Python is returning maybe because of the fact that the block matrix formed contains all $1$'s and that Python potentially thinks that in general you are asking, a speacial case of $\frac{\partial A}{\partial B}$ for general matrices $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^n$.